# How to query for special characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a large table filled with vendor information.

I need to split this list into two separate lists based on column `VENDOR_NAME`. One list where `VENDOR_NAME` is all regular characters and numbers, another list where `VENDOR_NAME` is special/foreign characters.

I am not sure what the `SELECT` statements would be to view this information off of the existing master table. Then I could just create two new tables.

1. `VENDOR_NAME` only numbers and regular characters
2. `VENDOR_NAME` only foreign characters

Example:

Regular: BLUE RIBBON TAG & LABEL CORP

Foreign: 俞章平

Regular: ULSTER-SOCIETY OF GASTROENTEROLOGY/1

Foreign: 马建忠

Comment: How do you define _regular characters_ and _foreign characters_? Is regular characters [0-9,a-Z]?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Examples, examples, examples. Would be better if you provided sample of source data, DML to quickly reproduce your table structure and populate it with sample data. And, of course, desired output.

Comment: @JPW- Yes 0-9, a-z, pretty much anything I can type on my keyboard as well. By foreign character I mean Chinese type characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the function ASCIISTR():

> `ASCIISTR` takes as its argument a string, or an expression that
>   resolves to a string, in any character set and returns an ASCII
>   version of the string in the database character set. Non-ASCII
>   characters are converted to the form \xxxx, where xxxx represents a
>   UTF-16 code unit.

To get all strings without special characters:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE INSTR(ASCIISTR(vendor_name),'\') = 0
```

You have to take care, of course, that strings with '\' would be filtered out by this as well, since the backslash is translated to '\005C' by ASCIISTR. Maybe like this:

```
WHERE INSTR(REPLACE(ASCIISTR(vendor_name),'\005C','_' ),'\') = 0
```

Comment: Thank you that worked quite well, do you have any recommendation as to how to find all the other rows now to put into a separate table? A "select everything else" query if you will... or Select everything that is NOT the above query?

Comment: @DillonTagle If this answer was useful to you, please vote up and/or accept it. See  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Replacing existing backslashes before the ASCIISTR  also worked for me:   WHERE INSTR(ASCIISTR(REPLACE(vendor_name,'\','_')),'\') = 0